# what is the better way to use sprintf for multiple inputs?

Tags: c

I have more than 50 input to add to buffer and make a string out of it.
For understanding purpose, lets say.

L1, L2, L3 are structures having multiple variables like

```
struct L1{
int a;
int b;
int c;
};
struct L2{
int l;
int m;
};
struct L3{
int p;
int q;
int r;
int s;
};
```

.

```
sprintf(buffer, "%s,%s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",time, pDeviceMO->getName(), L1.a, L1.b, L2.l, L3.q, L3.s, L2.m, L3.p, L3.r, L1.c);
```

than write buffer to a File.

```
fprintf(File, "%s,%s\n",deviceSerialNum, buffer);
```

is there a better way?

Maybe like multiple sprintf for each input. (from a better coding perspective)

Comment: Are the "input" part of an array? Then use a simple loop with `strcat`?

Comment: I have in existed code, where inputs are coming from different modules.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
no variables are different. :(

Comment: Why do you have more than fifty separate variables in a single function?

Comment: Sounds like a [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @melpomene It's a performance stats module, having multiple stats inputs coming from different modules.

Comment: @GoWind could you please provide more code, how you get and access the incoming data

Comment: edited question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no better way. Ex. see kernel proc outputing, ex. [meminfo](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/meminfo.c#L34). You just *need* to go through all variables.

You can have a [single big call](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/nfsd/stats.c#L41). Or chain multiple calls like:

```
int pos = 0;
pos += sprintf(&buffer[pos], "%d", var1);
pos += sprintf(&buffer[pos], "%d", var2);
pos += sprintf(&buffer[pos], "%d", var3);
```

(without error checking), but you need to go through all variables anyway. Anyway I would advise you to use `snprintf`.

If all variables have the same type, you can have some fun with it:

```
int pos = 0;
int *list[] = { &var1, &var2, &var3, ... };
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(list)/sizeof(*list); ++i) {
    pos = sprintf(&buffer[pos], "%d,", *list[i]);
}
```

It looks fancy, but there is really no point in it. Once other people start reading your code, it will become unreadable and a mess. Stick to simple `snprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

If splitting the single `sprintf` with 50 variables is the only issue, then you can use multiple `sprintf` calls and use the return value to calculate the buffer position for the next part.

untested example

```
int chars;
int pos = 0;

chars = sprintf(buffer+pos, "%s", one);
if(chars > 0) pos += chars;

chars = sprintf(buffer+pos, ",%s", two);
if(chars > 0) pos += chars;

chars = sprintf(buffer+pos, ",%d", three);
if(chars > 0) pos += chars;
```

...

Of course you can use more than one value per `sprintf`

```
chars = sprintf(buffer+pos, "%s,%s,%d", one, two, three);
if(chars > 0) pos += chars;
```

Note that the code doesn't prevent possible buffer overflow. You could use `snprintf` to fix this, but with `snprintf` the return code is a bit more difficult to handle.

If all you want to do with the combined buffer is writing it to a file you can directly `fprintf` the individual values which would avoid the possible buffer overflow problem.

```
fprintf(File, "%s,",deviceSerialNum);
fprintf(File, "%s,", one);
fprintf(File, "%s,", two);
fprintf(File, "%d,", three);
/* ... */
fprintf(File, "%d\n", last);
```